# Asterisk in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I really need someone to help me.
I'm trying to learn Object C. But I don't understand the asterisk movement.
I will explain myself:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]
```

Here  we ask to the date method to create an NSdate instance and stored in date. Is that correct?

If I'm in the @interface and I do:

```
@interface Gretter : NSObject
{
 NSString  *greetings
}
```

Here we declare  Gretter subclass belonging to the NSObject superclass and we add the method greetings to the subclass greeting
Is that correct?

What i really don't understand is:

```
NSString* greeting = @"hello"
```

Why is the asterisk attach to the NSString* here??

This are 3 separate example and not part of the same program.
I just want to understand why the asterisk* change position

Thank you very much

CL

Comment: It's Objective-C, not Object C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer each of your questions in turn:

*Here we ask to the date method to create an NSdate instance and stored in date. Is that correct?*

Yes, that's correct.  That's a slightly strange way to say it, but you have the right idea.

*Here we declare Gretter subclass belonging to the NSObject superclass and we add the method greetings to the subclass greeting Is that correct?*

Your correct that `Gretter` is a subclass of `NSObject`.  However, what you've added is an instance variable called `greetings`, not a method.

*Why is the asterisk attach to the NSString* here??*

The position of the asterisk really doesn't matter.  In each case you are creating/defining/initializing a pointer to an object.  `NSString* foo` is the same as `NSString *foo` is the same as `NSString * foo`.  Its just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
NSString* greeting = @"hello";
```

And this:

```
NSString *greeting = @"hello";
```

Are exactly the same, you are defining a pointer to a string object.

Comment: To the compiler, those are not similar, they are exactly the same. It's just a difference in white space. Don't forget `NSString * greeting = @"hello";`